# Install Site: false ignored

Tags: virtual-machine

I am using the DrupalVM '1.8.6' / Vagrant.

In my Config I say

```
install_site: false
```

Still a Drupal site is installed. How can I stop Vagrant from doing this each time I run `vagrant up --provision`.

Answer (score 1):

I always make sure the "build_xx" properties are false as well.  E.g.:

```
build_composer: false
build_makefile: false
build_composer_project: false
```

YMMV

Comment: All of them are false...

Comment: All of them are false...

build_composer: false
build_composer_project: false
build_makefile: false

Still the site is installed automatically by using drush.